# Why is TD(0) not converging to the optimal policy?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reinforce, td-lambda

I am trying to implement the basic RL algorithms to learn on [this](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/reinforcejs/gridworld_td.html) 10x10 GridWorld (from REINFORCEJS by Kaparthy).

Currently I am stuck at TD(0). No matter how many episodes I run, when I am updating the policy after all episodes are done according to the value function I dont get the optimal value function which I obtain when *toggle td learning* on the grid from the link I provided above.

The only way I am getting the optimal policy is when I am updating the policy in each iteration and then following the updated policy when calculating the TD target. But according to the algorithm from Sutton and Barto a given policy (which is fixed over all episodes - see line 1 below) should be evaluated.
[image: TD0FromSuttonAndBarto]

Using `alpha=0.1` and `gamma=0.9` after 1000 episodes my Td(0) algo finds the following value function

```
[[-0.04 -0.03 -0.03 -0.05 -0.08 -0.11 -0.09 -0.06 -0.05 -0.07]
 [-0.08 -0.04 -0.04 -0.06 -0.1  -0.23 -0.11 -0.06 -0.07 -0.11]
 [-0.13  -inf  -inf  -inf  -inf -0.58  -inf  -inf  -inf -0.25]
 [-0.24 -0.52 -1.23 -2.6   -inf -1.4  -1.28 -1.12 -0.95 -0.62]
 [-0.28 -0.49 -0.87 -1.28  -inf -2.14 -2.63 -1.65 -1.38 -1.04]
 [-0.27 -0.42 -0.64 -0.94  -inf  0.97 -1.67 -2.01 -2.79 -1.62]
 [-0.26 -0.36 -0.69 -0.93  -inf -1.17 -1.72 -1.92 -2.75 -1.82]
 [-0.25 -0.38 -0.67 -2.27  -inf -2.62 -2.74 -1.55 -1.31 -1.14]
 [-0.23 -0.31 -0.66 -1.2  -0.98 -1.24 -1.48 -1.02 -0.7  -0.7 ]
 [-0.2  -0.29 -0.43 -0.62 -0.64 -0.77 -0.87 -0.67 -0.54 -0.48]]
```

where `-inf`are walls in the grid. If I update the policy according to that value function I am getting.

```
[['e   ' 'e   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'e   ' 'e   ' 's   ' 'w   ']
 ['e   ' 'n   ' 'n   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'e   ' 'e   ' 'e   ' 'n   ' 'w   ']
 ['n   ' 'XXXX' 'XXXX' 'XXXX' 'XXXX' 'n   ' 'XXXX' 'XXXX' 'XXXX' 'n   ']
 ['n   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 's   ' 'XXXX' 'n   ' 'e   ' 'e   ' 'e   ' 'n   ']
 ['n   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'XXXX' 's   ' 'n   ' 'n   ' 'n   ' 'n   ']
 ['s   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'XXXX' 's   ' 'w   ' 'n   ' 'n   ' 'n   ']
 ['s   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'XXXX' 'n   ' 'w   ' 's   ' 's   ' 's   ']
 ['s   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'XXXX' 'n   ' 'e   ' 's   ' 's   ' 's   ']
 ['s   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 's   ' 's   ' 's   ' 's   ' 'e   ' 's   ' 's   ']
 ['n   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'w   ' 'e   ' 'e   ' 'e   ' 'w   ']]
```

where `(n, w, s, e)` = `(north, west, south, east)`. According to the result from Andrey Kaparthys simulation (from [here](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/reinforcejs/gridworld_td.html)) the final policy should look like this

[image: ReinforceJSResult]

Notes:

- I did not use any exploration
- when the agent ends up in the final state `[5, 5]` I used the value of the starting state `[0, 0]` as the value of its successor state `V(S_{t+1})`. The episode is then finished and the agent starts again in the starting state.
- In **every** state the agent takes a random action taken from north, west, south or east. If he ends in a wall the value of the next state is just the value where the agent currently is in. And it stays in its state and takes a random action again.

I am scratching my head on this for a while now but I dont understand what I am missing.

1. The value function has to converge. Meaning my policy should be the same as on the website (picture 2)?
2. Only the value of my final state is positive while on the website simulation the whole optimal trajectory has positive values. I know that this is because on the website they update the policy in every step. But shouldn't it also work without updating it iteratively like I did it?
3. Since I am taking a random action (from `n,w,s,e`) in every step in every episode for example state `[6, 5]` or `[6, 6]` (the one below the terminal state) can not really take advantage of the positivity of the terminal state since they are surrounded by more negative-reward-states than this positive-reward-state. This is why after so many iterations the values are getting negative.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The image shows an algorithm used to estimate value function of a given policy, so why do you expect that algorithm to provide you with the optimal value function or optimal policy? You will only evaluate how good is your given policy from this algorithm nothing more.

Comment: You are right, I did not understand that correctly. Its onlz evaluating but not optimizing. Implementing Q-Learning will probably give me the optimal policy. Thanks.